# Publish app with the copyright of other company

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

My company have been chosen to develop an app for another company.
Once this app is published, in the AppStore it will appear our team as the developers but we want to appear the name of that other company on the copyright.

My concern is if I will get any kind of problems in the review process for the AppStore, like if I'll need to provide some document proving that I've the right to publish that app in name of that company.

Best regards,

Javier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company that's going to sell the app needs to create its own account in the appstore, then it has to assign someone as agent for the company.  Only that person is allowed to post to the App Store, so be careful in your choice.